# Refactoring: how to remove a model?

Tags: django, django-models, refactoring

I have a model which is causing too much complexity, and so I want to do away with it and move to a simpler way of doing things. I don't immediately want to scrap the data in this database table, though.

```
class PRSblock( models.Model):
    PRS = models.ForeignKey( 'jobs.PRS2', models.CASCADE, related_name='prs_blocks')
    # no other relational fields
```

So, first, migrate the related name `prs_blocks` to `obsolete_prs_blocks` and then in the `PRS` model, add a `@property` `prs_blocks`  that will `assert` that it is never called (to trap any bits of code which I failed to remove)

Second, rename the model `PRSblock` to `obsolete_PRSblock`. IIRC Django makemigrations will ask whether I renamed it, and if I say yes, it will  preserve the database table.

Does this sound sensible or are there any gotchas I haven't though of?

Comment: Do you need the property? Removing the related_name (set it to `+`) would do the same job by generating AttributeErrors instead.

Comment: @Iain_Shelvington probably. Almost certainly. I prefer to assert that impossible is indeed impossible, just in case.

Comment: @Iain_Shelvington setting the related name to `'+'` is a good idea, though. I'd forgotten one could do that.